# DWR instantiate a class every time a method is called

Tags: java, javascript, arraylist, dwr

I am trying to pass an arraylist that will be populated in method A of Class X and tehn I want to use teh same arraylist in method B of the same class. But since I am using DWR to access my java classes from JavaScripts, every time I am calling a method it is instantiates the class again and I loose the data inside the Arraylist in the process. 
I am wondering if there is a work around or a formal way of passing the array list.
Thanks!

Comment: I am not aware of DWR but you can make your arraylist as static for no initializing for every instance

Comment: This worked, I am not sure about the consequences of doing this. Thanks though